# Facing issue with filtering values at API using GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, lambda

I am getting data at Db like below

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE | ColF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | C-1234 | 121 | R-123 | 78417 | 346 |
| 100 | C-1234 | 124 | R-124 | 78417 | 346 |
| 100 | C-4586 | 146 | R-146 | 78741 | 374 |
| 101 | C-7124 | 165 | R-165 | 58517 | 475 |
| 101 | C-8547 | 174 | R-174 | 47417 | 854 |

My Class is

```
Public ClassA
{

Public ClassA()
{
PropF=new List<SubClassA>();
}
public int ColA{get;set;}
public int ColB{get;set;}
public int ColC{get;set;}
public int ColD{get;set;}
public int ColE{get;set;}
public int ColF{get;set;}
public List<SubClassA> PropF(get;set;}
}

public SubClassA
{
public int ColB{get;set;}
public int ColC{get;set;}
public int ColD{get;set;}
public int ColE{get;set;}
public int ColF{get;set;}
}
```

I am calling above class properties

```
public Gedetails()
{
ClassA obj = Sql.getDetails().toList(); // which will give me list of values into Obj.


}
```

I am expecting the classA values to be grouped by ColA and then add to list of values shown below

Please let me know how can i get the output properly values like the one shown below and changes required on the class level. Kindly suggest.

Can I apply group by `ColA` and divide the `subclassA` into another subclass and insert values into it.

```
100
 --346
   -C-1234    121   R-123    78417
   -C-1234    124   R-124    78417
--374
   -C-4586    146   R-146    78741
101
 --475
   -C-7124    165   R-165    58517
 --854
   -C-8547    174   R-174    47417
```

Comment: Where's the code for `Sql.getDetails()`?

Comment: From your result, you are trying to perform a nested group? First group by `ColA`, then (in each grouped `ColA`) group by `ColF`?

Comment: @YongShun- I ma thinking the same. But how can we achieve with some less coding. Please share code snippet if you have any

Comment: @NickBailey-Actually its another method which calls stored procedure which would return result  as shown above.

Comment: Your requirement is unclear, but if you want to achieve as what I mentioned in previous comment, you can look for this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JzRWPc). `ClassA obj = Sql.getDetails().toList();` this line I think is invalid as LINQ `.ToList()` returns `List<T>`, but `obj` is a single object which is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking to do something along the lines of:

```
List<Details> details = Sql.getDetails().toList();
List<ClassA> classAList =
    details
    .GroupBy(d => d.ColA)
    .Select(grp => new ClassA {
        ColA = grp.Key,
        SubClassBCollection = grp
            .GroupBy(d => d.ColB) // A group within a group 
            .Select(grp => new SubclassB {
                ColB = grp.Key,
                SubClassCCollection = grp
                    .Select(d => new SubclassC {
                        ColC = d.ColC,
                        ColD = d.ColD,
                        ColE = d.ColE,
                        ColF = d.ColF
                    }) // SubclassC
                    .ToList() // List of C contained in B
            }) // SubclassB
            .ToList() // List of B contained in A
    }) // ClassA
    .ToList(); // List of A
```

This would populate a hierarchy of classes having the following (informal) structure:

- ClassA: ColA, SubClassBCollection
- SubclassB: ColB, SubClassCCollection
- SubclassC: ColC, ColD, ColE, ColF